# Does Office 365 Education include SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, office-365

I have Office 365 Education subscription through my college. Am I able to use SharePoint through it? As I log in to my Office 365 account, I can see the SharePoint link. But once I click on it, it gives me the error related to "MS SharePoint Foundation". What does it mean? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://products.office.com/en-us/academic/compare-office-365-education-plans) comparison of licenses, both the Education and Education E5 licenses should come with SharePoint (the **Intranet site for your teams with customizable security settings** feature).  However, tenant administrators can restrict access to features, so it's possible you simply do not have access.

Comment: So can I ask them to give me access as comparison shows I am eligible to access SharePoint Online?

Comment: You can ask, but that doesn't mean they'll give you access.  SharePoint Online is a tenant feature, not a playground for individual users.

Comment: Okay. Will give it a try by asking the administrators. Thanks a lot..!!